# How to sort data according to a category/subject php

Tags: php

I would like to program a grade management system for the organization and digitization of my school affairs. As a first step, I would like to display the grades in a table: (The grades according to the German school system)

I want to display the following table (HTML):

```
<table>
<!--- header --->
<tr>
    <th>Subject</th>
    <!--- "count" of the mark --->
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
    <th>5</th>
    <th>6</th>
    <th>7</th>
    <th>...</th>
</tr>

<!--- subject and marks --->
<tr>
    <th>Biology</th>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>2</th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th>Math</th>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
</tr>
...
</table>
```

To save the grades I created a mysql database:

```
subject | mark | username
------------------------
biology | 1    | Max
biology | 3    | Max
biology | 2    | Max
math    | 1    | Max
math    | 1    | Max
math    | 2    | Max
...
```

To get the data from the database I use this code:

```
$stmt = $mysql->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE USERNAME = :username");
$stmt->bindParam(":username", $_SESSION['USERNAME']);
$stmt->execute();
```

In my program the user is *$_SESSION['USERNAME'] = "Max"*.

My problem is that I don't know how to adapt the table to the grades and output each grade as a single column!

- Important

For my problem I dont want to use...

```
SELECT * FROM table WHER SUBJECT = 'Subject'
```

...because there will be more categories and I want a clean system where I dont have to change code when I add a new subject.

Comment: you are looking for pivot table. There are plenty of examples also here on SO on how to build them

Comment: Where does count of the mark supposed to come from?